# CodeIgniter File Uploading Class , encrypt_name

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

HI, is there any way to limit the characters that the uploading class assigns to the filename.

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with `max_filename` parameter.

[From CI User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) :

> max_filename: The maximum length that a file name can be. Set to zero for no limit.

**Update:**
If you wanna do that with encrypt_name you may set `file_name` parameter.

```
$config['file_name'] = substr(md5($file_name),15);
```

Comment: There is no easy way. You must extend Upload library.